# If input has a value, add it to a variable in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So I am new to PHP and I'm trying to create a spreadsheet-like program. I have a form with columns and cells, and the user can add and delete rows (using Javascript). Once the data in the cells has been entered, the user can save the sheet and the data is displayed in the same cells. I have been able to get this to work, but I have to manually check each input and put the data into a variable, and then display that variable in the cells. I'm trying to find a way to automatically get all the data from the cells, and store each one into a variable with incrementing id's. The problem is, I want the user to be able to add infinite rows with infinite cells; so how would I get all the data if I don't know how many cells there will be?

I don't know if I am even going about this the right way, so I'm hoping someone can at least point me in the right direction. Like I said, I'm new to PHP so I may be completely ignorant and thinking about this completely wrong.

Note: I'm not looking for a copy/paste answer, but more of guidance on the theory of accomplishing this. Of course the plan is to eventually store all the inputted data into a MySQL table, and then display it on the screen from there; but, I'm first trying to solve this problem.

This is what I have so far:

**PHP**

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $a1_post = $_POST['a1']; 
  $a2_post = $_POST['a2'];
  $a3_post = $_POST['a3'];

  $b1_post = $_POST['b1'];
  $b2_post = $_POST['b2'];
  $b3_post = $_POST['b3'];
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="table-form" method="post" action="">  
  <div class="column" id="column-a">
    <p>Antigen</p>
     <input class="cell" id="a1" type="text" name="a1" value="<?php echo $a1_post; ?>">
     <input class="cell" id="a2" type="text" name="a2" value="<?php echo $a2_post; ?>">
     <input class="cell" id="a3" type="text" name="a3" value="<?php echo $a3_post; ?>">    
    </div>
  <div class="column" id="column-b">
   <p>Start Size</p>
      <input class="cell" id="b1" type="text" name="b1" value="<?php echo $b1_post; ?>">
      <input class="cell" id="b2" type="text" name="b2" value="<?php echo $b2_post; ?>">
      <input class="cell" id="b3" type="text" name="b3" value="<?php echo $b3_post; ?>">
   </div>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: i would start by building a multi dimensional array from the form. ie `name="[a]1"` etc

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use a naming convention you can just iterate over `$_POST` and update your table as necessary...

To simplify this process name your inputs with square brackets:

```
    <input class="cell" id="c1" type="text" name="c[0]" value="<?php echo $c[0]; ?>" />
    <input class="cell" id="c2" type="text" name="c[1]" value="<?php echo $c[1]" />
```

When you submit your data will already be in an array per row:

$_POST would equal

```
[
  'c' => ['c1 value', 'c2 value']
];
```

So you can interact with your dataset by iterating over $_POST:

```
foreach ($_POST as $rowName => $row) {
  //$row equals ['c1 value', 'c2 value']
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any documentation on this? I think I understand but I'm having trouble getting it to work for me. If I echo $row or $row[1] within the foreach function, I get the inputted value. But when I try value="<?php echo $a[1]; ?>" or value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>"  I get nothing.